# Realtor.ca web api call failure

Tags: excel, vba, web-services

I have a code programmed in Excel VBA that gets the name of real estate broker and finds his/her agent ID. It was done by a regular http GET request till this January. Recently the Realtor.ca website was redone and now they use asmx Web services to get the data.

I replicated the web request (didn't use all request headers as I judged that most of them are not required), but can't make it work. I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is the excerpt of the code:

```
Public Function findRealtorIDbyName(iFirstName As String, iLastName As String) As Double
    Dim Request As XMLHttp
    Dim ApiMsg  As String 
    Dim Doc As DOMDocument60
    ApiMsg = "firstName=" & iFirstName & "&lastName=" & iLastName & "&provinceIds=4&recordsPerPage=20&currentPage=1&sortBy=3&sortOrder=A"

    With Request
        .Open "POST", "https://www.realtor.ca/Services/ControlFetcher.asmx/GetRealtorResults", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
        .send ApiMsg 
        Doc.LoadXML .responseText
    End With

    If Request.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "The Request returned " & Request.Status & Request.statusText
        findRealtorIDbyName = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    ...Code to find the ID from the XML... 

End Function
```

And the calling routine:

```
Public Sub test_findRealtorIDbyName()

    Dim result As Double

    result = findRealtorIDbyName("Vanessa", "Spaccucci")

    MsgBox result

End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a few test names and ids we can verify our testing with?

Comment: Sure thing, here you go:
Vanessa Spaccucci - 1882535, 
Pierre Vachon - 162423, 
Brigitte Burdman - 1439060

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, the URL that you are calling returns a 500 error because the page you were calling before has changed. You will need to change the url that you are calling. You might want to review the [github page here](https://github.com/Froren/realtorca) for some information about the API. For instance, it looks like you might want to use the organizationID parameter to retrieve results for a particular realtor.

Comment: I saw that github page before posting my question.There is only one API - PropertySearch_Post - specified there. That API didn't change and I have no problems calling it. That API needs the person ID as an input and to find the person ID I need to make the API in question work. That's why I am here for help :)